# React - trying to change state in child component from function in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, state

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state = { isDialogOpen: false }
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isDialogOpen: false })
  }
   handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isDialogOpen: true })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleOpen}>Open Dialog</Button>
        <ChildComponent isOpen={isDialogOpen} onClose={this.handleClose}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      setStyle: false
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(!isOpen && prevProps.isOpen && setStyle !== prevState.setStyle) { 
     // make some API call here to fetch and display data in dialog box 
     // action from react-redux
      someAPIfunction()
    }

  handleSetStyle() {
    this.setState({
      setStyle: true
    })
  }
 
 const {setStyle } = this.state; 
 const showTextStyle = setStyle ? 'some-css' : null 
  render() {
    return <DialogComponentLibrary isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <p className={showTextStyle}>{someDataFromAPI}</p>
        <Button onClick={this.handleSetStyle}>SET STYLE</Button>
    </Dialog>
  }
}
```

The current behaviour is that when I click on "SET STYLE" button in the child component, it is setting the state setStyle as true and re-rendering the dialog component with the new style. However, when I close the dialog component, setStyle is still 'true'. I need to set 'setStyle' to 'false' whenever I close the child component. I was thinking of having the 'setStyle' state in the parent component, and in the handleClose function in the parent component,  I am resetting setStyle to false.  I then tried to read in the prop setStyle in the child component and included it as a state. However, still not sure how I can change the setStyle state to true within the child component as onClose is still being controlled by the parent component.

Appreciate any ideas, thank you.

Comment: I guess your ChildComponent never unmounts? If so then I would suggest you to change the state whenever you close the dialog. Something like <Dialog onClose={ () => {this.setState(); this.props.onClose();} } />

Comment: you shouln't be using class components anymore. Unless it's some legacy project but just saying in case you don't realise

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a handler containing both onClose and setState method.

```
handleClose = () => {
this.setState({setStyle: false});
this.props.onClose();
}
```

and pass this handler to your Dialog Component's onClose method.

```
<Dialog isOpen={isOpen} onClose={this.handleClose}>
```